# Find the arc length of the curve $x = 1/6*(y^2+ 3)^{3/2}$ from $y = 0$ to $y = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am trying to find the arclength of the curve $$x = 1/6\cdot\left(y^2 + 3\right)^{3/2},\;\; 0\leq y\leq 1$$   I got this far and now I am stuck and don't know what to do next. Any help please?

$$\begin{align} dx & =  \left(1/6\right)\cdot\left(3/2\right)\cdot\left(y^2 + 3\right)^{1/2}\cdot\left(2y\right)\\ \\ 
& =  (1/4)(2y)\cdot\left(y^2 + 3\right)^{1/2}\\ \\
&  =  (y/2)\cdot\left(y^{2}+3\right)^{1/2}\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}L & = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + \left(y/2\left(y^2 + 3\right)^{1/2}\right)^{2}}\\ \\
 &= \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + \left(y^{2}/4\right)\left(y^2 + 3\right)}\\ \\
 &= \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + \left(y^{4} + 3y^{2}\right)/4}\end{align}$$

Comment: se LaTeX-MathJax for mathematics, otherwise it is very, very hard t understand what you wrote.

Comment: @DonAntonio fixed...was in the process of fixing it and amWhy fixed it for me

Comment: Can you let me know if I got it right? (formatting?) I had to add a parenthesis for the latex to render.

Comment: @amWhy you got it right! thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Are you sure that you are expected to get an exact result? You could proceed from here using an approximation techniques, like Simpson's Rule. Simpson's Rule with $n=2$ already gives a result correct to four decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpson's Rule with n=2 already gives a result correct to four decimal places.

$$\frac16\left(1+4\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1}{2^4}+3\left(\frac{1}{2^2}\right)\right)/4}+\sqrt{2}\right)\approx1.1336\ldots$$

(A CAS says that the integral is $1.13359\ldots$)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong:

The derivative of the curve $f(y)$, if parametrized by the arc-length, will be fixed on $1$.
So if you do not want to evaluate the integral, you can solve for $y$:
$$g(t) \equiv f \circ y(t)=x$$
Then find $t_1$ for which $y(t_1)=1$ and the answer will be $g(t_1)$.